# Integrating ImageMagick into existing Visual Studio C# solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, imagemagick

I am developing on a Windows 7 64bit machine. I have a solution in Visual Studio using C# and am trying to add the solution for ImageMagick I found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/ImageMagick_in_VBNET.aspx) to my project.

I managed to add the solution to my project, checked the linker and c/c++ general settings as well as the common properties and all appears to be in order. I also added a reference in my project to ImageMagickNET8 (the name of the ImageMagick project).

When I try to make a call to the ImageMagick project:
ImageMagickNET.Image img = new ImageMagickNET.Image("c:\picture.jpg");

...the following exception is thrown:
BadImageFormatException was unhandled
Could not load file or assembly 'ImageMagickNET8, Version=1.0.4189.18742, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

I assume I am forgetting something fundamental about adding a project to my existing project.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that ImageMagick is set to compile to x86 only, instead of Any CPU. Try changing your project to be x86.  Project + Properties, Build tab, Platform target setting.

Comment: I changed the solution to be x86 and I noticed the chosen platform for ImageMagickNET8 is Win32. Now when I run I get the same exception, BadImageFormatException, but with a new message: is not a valid Win32 application. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700C1).  Also it may be worth noting that it is stopping in Program.cs on the line Application.Run(new PhotoLoader());

Comment: I actually managed to fix this by going the opposite, setting it to x64 in the project settings.